# Eclipse missing Maven Preferences

Tags: eclipse, maven

I installed Maven to my computer, but Eclipse don't have Maven Preferences.

[image]

version `eclipse-jee-helios-linux-gtk-x86_64`

Comment: Did you install the Eclipse maven support plug-ins? Without the plug-in Eclipse won't know about maven. Also Eclipse Helios is now 12 years and 22 releases old, the maven support will be very out of date.

Comment: @greg-449 i working in offline server, can i install Eclipse maven support plug-ins. Thanks you.

Comment: I'm not sure what "offline server" means, but you need access to a Eclipse update site or install that includes the maven support

Comment: @greg-449 thanks you, i will try another version of eclipse.

Comment: Please try the *current* version of Eclipse.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core#-installation